# How to automate data loading from CSV file into Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to automate data loading from CSV file into Azure SQL. I have tried following this guide https://marczak.io/posts/azure-loading-csv-to-sql/ which works perfectly for smaller files but when I try use larger files I get this error:
"status": 504,
      "message": "Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.\r\nclientRequestId: 347b83c3-0fd9-414f-8795-ce4843d85ebd"

Note: the csv file I am testing is the same as in the example just with extra rows.

I am only very new to azure so any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction) to help you lode the csv file to Azure SQL database.

Please reference this tutorial: [Copy data from Azure Blob storage to a SQL database by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal):

In this tutorial, you create a data factory by using the Azure Data Factory user interface (UI). The pipeline in this data factory copies data from Azure Blob storage to a SQL database. The configuration pattern in this tutorial applies to copying from a file-based data store to a relational data store.

Data Factory has the feature to [Trigger the pipeline on a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal#trigger-the-pipeline-on-a-schedule):

In this schedule, you create a schedule trigger for the pipeline. The trigger runs the pipeline on the specified schedule, such as hourly or daily.

This feature can help you automate data loading from CSV file into Azure SQL.

Hope this helps.